What is the power of a set
I'm currently reading the article Ultraproducts and saturated models by H.J. Keisler (link: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82090773.pdf). In lemma 1.1, he talks about a set having power $\alpha$. I'm assuming that by this he means that the cardinal of the structures considered is $\alpha$ (as this is a result I knew beforehand), but then why does he refer to it as the power of the set? Could he be referring to that the power of the universe of the structure is of cardinal $\alpha$?
I attach a picture of the lemma I'm talking about, thanks in advance for your help.


yes, that is absolutely right! "power" is an older term for cardinality. it seems not so in-fashion to me now, but my sense is that it was quite often used historically; eg Morley's paper proving his famous categoricity theorem was called "Categoricity in Power"

(maybe someone who knows some history of math can weigh in on the historical usage of the term)

@Atticus Stonestrom (and the OP): For historical usage of the term, see What were the not-so-convincing reasons for using the word "power" for power sets? AND "Potency set" for power set? AND Was "potency set" used for power set?

The term derived from the English translation of Georg Cantor's original papers on set theory: Grundlagen (1883): "concept of power [Machtigkeitsbegriff]: two sets have the same power if they can be, element for element, correlated
with one another reciprocally and one-to-one." From that, also the term "power of the continuum".
